# how can a .phar file be executed in command line

Tags: php, phar

I don't understand how a `.phar` file can be executed in command line in linux. If it can be executed just by entering the filename, it shoudl have been converted to binary.

The usual way of executing a php file would be by entering `php filename.php` (asking the php interpreter to execute the file) . but in the case of a .phar file the file gets executed automatically even though what it contains is a php application. how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the beginning of the file. If it is a script, shell, php, python, whatever script, it has its own interpreter at the very beginning in the syntax of

`#!/bin/interpeter`

and if the file has `+x` permission, it can be executed as if it was a normal binary executable file.

Comment: I have downloaded the syfony.phar file from http://symfony.com. it contains a php script in the root folder. but doesnt have a syntax like you mentioned

Comment: curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer > symfony.phar

Comment: it does, try running: `$ curl -LsS symfony.com/installer | head -n1`, it will show up `#!/usr/bin/env php`

Comment: is there a way that i can see this file in a text editor

Comment: it does seem to be compiled somehow, not a plain php file, so i don't know, but anyway this is another question, a bit OT